# Deploying to shinyapps.io ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to deploy a Shinyapp that works fine locally. I use rsconnect like so:

```
# I use my actual token and secret
    rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='myname',
                  token='<TOKEN>',
                  secret='<SECRET>')
```

I then receive a confirmation message in the deployment pane of Rstudio:

```
Deployment completed: https://myname.shinyapps.io/my_app/
```

However, when I try to visit the link I only see this message:

```
ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

I've pasted the logs from within Shiny GUI below.

There's a csv file in my apps directly that provides the data for the app. I'm not sure if the issue I'm seeing is related to directly path.

Nowhere in the application am I using `setwd()`

Here's a screen of my directory structure:
[image]

Within server() I then read in the data:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  # get data
  ga_data <- read.csv("ga_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
```

I'm not sure if the reading of the csv is the issue or not, it might be a diversion.

Here are the logs from within Shinyapps GUI for the application:

```
2017-12-05T06:35:09.578323+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: 
2017-12-05T06:35:09.578336+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Starting R with process ID: '18'
2017-12-05T06:35:09.593403+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:32896
2017-12-05T06:35:09.593401+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: 
2017-12-05T06:35:09.423094+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: RJSONIO version: NA
2017-12-05T06:35:09.423059+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: R version: 3.3.3
2017-12-05T06:35:09.423078+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: knitr version: NA
2017-12-05T06:35:09.423074+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: rmarkdown version: NA
2017-12-05T06:35:09.423084+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: jsonlite version: 1.4
2017-12-05T06:35:09.423102+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: htmltools version: 0.3.5
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886750+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Server version: 1.5.10-6
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886783+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886784+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: R version: 3.3.3
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886784+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: shiny version: 1.0.3
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886785+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: rmarkdown version: NA
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886785+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: knitr version: NA
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886798+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: RJSONIO version: NA
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886786+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: jsonlite version: 1.4
2017-12-05T06:48:30.886825+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: htmltools version: 0.3.5
2017-12-05T06:48:31.081733+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: 
2017-12-05T06:48:31.074740+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
2017-12-05T06:48:31.081735+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Starting R with process ID: '248'
2017-12-05T06:48:31.112053+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: 
2017-12-05T06:48:31.112056+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:44798
2017-12-05T06:48:31.153820+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
2017-12-05T06:48:31.153822+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
2017-12-05T06:48:31.154157+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Warning in utils::install.packages(package, ...) :
2017-12-05T06:48:31.154158+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:   'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
2017-12-05T06:48:31.155312+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Warning: Error in utils::install.packages: unable to install packages
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160190+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Stack trace (innermost first):
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160191+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     59: utils::install.packages
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160192+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     58: withCallingHandlers
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160192+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     57: p_install
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160193+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     56: FUN
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160194+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     53: pacman::p_load
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160194+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     54: sapply
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160193+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     55: lapply
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160195+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     13: runApp
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160195+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     12: fn
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160196+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     11: doTryCatch
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160196+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:     10: tryCatchOne
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160196+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      9: tryCatchList
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160197+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      8: tryCatch
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160198+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      7: connect$retry
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160198+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      6: eval
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160199+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      5: eval
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160199+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      4: eval
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160200+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      3: eval
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160200+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      2: eval.parent
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160200+00:00 shinyapps[244428]:      1: local
2017-12-05T06:48:31.160485+00:00 shinyapps[244428]: Error : An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

If anyone can help me overcome this error I'd be grateful. If there's more information I can provide let me know.

Comment: I added ```options(shiny.sanitize.errors = F)``` to try to see what the error is but nothing changed

Comment: It seems like pacman is causing the problems and according to a quick google search, pacman is not supported for deployed shiny apps. https://github.com/trinker/pacman/issues/82 I'd suggest you try the `library()`-command instead of `p_load()`

Comment: @brettljausn Yup, that did the trick. Thank you very much for the tip